# Native js or Underscore, get all values from an object and put into string

Tags: javascript

Hi I just want to get all the string values from an object.
IE :

```
var myObject = {
value1 : 'this is one',
value2 : 'this is two,
value3 : 'this is three'
```

}

and return `"this is one, this is two, this is three"` string
 in the most efficient way possible ( or something close ) :)
is using 'reduce' the best way ?

also bonus question, what if I wanted to ignore value3 so I would get 
"this is one, this is two"
Thanks for any input !

Comment: [RTFM](http://underscorejs.org/#values) (+[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Underscore.js**

There is `_.values` function designed for this. Join the resultant array into string, you get:

```
var values = _.values(myObject).join(', '); // Put any delimiter you want
// ["this is one, this is two, this is three"]
```

**With concrete JavaScript**

Take the object keys, obtain the value and join them into string:

```
var values = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key){
    return myObject[key]
}).join(', '); // put any delimiter you want

// ["this is one, this is two, this is three"]
```

Comment: nice, thanks ! I also got it using array.reduce, but this is even better.

Comment: it might be handy to make a named util function for map() to use w/ Object.keys to get values: `function val(k){return this[k];}` , to use like `vals=Object.keys(obj).map(val, obj)`, which saves the need for extra anons...

Comment: @dandavis Appreciate your additional comment.

Answer (score 0):

Without underscore, you would need to collect all the values, and join them together.

```js
function valueString(o, d) {
  var r = [];

  for (var p in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      r.push(o[p]);
    }
  }

  return r.join(d);
}

var myObject = {
  value1 : 'this is one',
  value2 : 'this is two',
  value3 : 'this is three'
};

console.log(valueString(myObject, ', '));
```